# Why is my exception handling not catching?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my html code that I am trying to create the exception handling for. I am trying to create the exceptions for the first form in this code.

```
<form id="survey" name="survey" method="post">
<div id="errorText"></div>
<fieldset class="labelfloatleft" id="contactinfo"><legend>Your Thoughts</legend>
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />

<label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"  />

<label for="emailaddress">Email Address</label>
<input type="email" name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" 
size="30" placeholder="foryou@yahoo.com" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset><legend>Best Movie</legend>

<input type="radio" name="movie" id="horror" value="horror" checked="checked"/>
<label for="horror">The Horror</label>

<input type="radio" name="movie" id="badabing" value="badabing" />
<label for="badabing">Bada-Bing Bada-Boom</label>

<input type="radio" name="movie" id="roll" value="roll" />
<label for="roll">Roll or Die</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset><legend>Comments</legend>
<label for="message">Your Opinion</label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="button" id="submitBtn"/>
<input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="button" />
</form>


<h2>Welcome To Our World</h2>

<p class="very">We are a small time movie theater looking to help inspire
people who come to our theater. Our theaters come with
fresh food, cold and hot drinks, souvenirs and comfortable
seats to help make your experience worth while.
</p>

<h2>Most Popular</h2>

<ul>
<li>The Horror</li> 
<li>Bada-Bing Bada-Boom</li> 
<li>Roll or Die</li>
</ul>


<h2>Prices</h2>
<table title="prices">
<tr>
    <th>Ticket</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Thursday Deal</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Adult</td>
    <td>$10.00</td>
    <td rowspan="3">Half-Off</td>
    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Child</td>
    <td>$6.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Senior</td>
    <td>$8.00</td>
</table>

<form id="price" name="price" method="post">

<fieldset><legend>Ticket Quantity</legend>
<label for="adultinput">Adult 15-60
<input type="text" id="adultinput" value="1" size="2"/>
</label>
<label for="childinput">Child 1-14
<input type="text" id="childinput" value="0" size="2"/>
</label>
<label for="seniorinput">Senior 50 and up
<input type="text" id="seniorinput" value="0" size="2"/>
</label>
</fieldset>

<input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="calculate" class="button" />
<input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="button" />
</form>
```

This is my exception handling code that I am trying to get working. However, no matter how much I modify it, it never shows correctly. I have ran it in Chrome and have tried using a debugger to help however I am still unable to show the exceptions when I click the submit button.

```
 "use strict";
var fnameComplete = true;
var lnameComplete = true;
var emailComplete = true;
var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
var lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
var email = document.getElementById("emailaddress").value;
var errorDiv = document.getElementById("errorText");

function verifyFname() {
var validity = true;    
var messageText = "";
var errorDiv = document.getElementById("errorText");
try {
    if(!(isNaN(fname.value)) || (fname.value === "")){
            fname.style.background = "rgb(255,233,233)";
            throw "Please enter your first name.";
        } 
}
catch(message) {
    validity = false;
    messageText = message;
}
finally{
    numErrorDiv.style.display = "block";
    fnameComplete = validity;
    errorDiv.innerHTML = messageText;
}
}

function verifyLname() {
var validity = true;    
var messageText = "";
var errorDiv = document.getElementById("errorText");
try {
    if(!(isNaN(lname.value)) || (lname.value === "")){
            lname.style.background = "rgb(255,233,233)";
            throw "Please enter your first name.";
        } 
}
catch(message) {
    validity = false;
    messageText = message;
}
finally{
    errorDiv.style.display = "block";
    lnameComplete = validity;
    errorDiv.innerHTML = messageText;
}
}

function verifyEmail() {
var validity = true;    
var messageText = "";
var errorDiv = document.getElementById("errorText");
try {
    if(email === "") {
        email.style.background = "rgb(255,233,233)";
        throw "Please enter your email.";
    }
}
catch(message) {
    validity = false;
    messageText = message;
}
finally{
    numErrorDiv.style.display = "block";
    emailComplete = validity;
    errorDiv.innerHTML = messageText;
}
}

function validateForm(e) {
if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent form from submitting
} else {
    e.returnValue = false; //prevent form from submitting in IE8
}
formValidity = true; //reset value for revalidation
verifyEmail();
verifyFname();
verifyLname();
if(formValidity === true) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
}
}

function createEventListeners() {
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
if (form.addEventListener){
    form.addEventListener("submit", validateForm, false);
} else if(form.attachEvent) {
    form.attachEvent("onsubmit", validateForm);
}
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener("load", createEventListeners, false);
} else if(window.attachEvent) {
window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListeners);
}
```

Comment: Hi, please indent your code and provide a specific example rather than the whole project. We don't need to see all of the fields of the form, one is enough.

Comment: Also, you need to include what your expected/real behaviour is or are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you try to access a non existing field.

Here you already get the values of the fields

```
var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
var lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
var email = document.getElementById("emailaddress").value;
```

And in your comparisons you try to access a value field again. But you already have the plain value

```
if(!(isNaN(lname.value)) || (lname.value === "")){
}
```

Do it this way instead

```
if(!(isNaN(lname)) || (lname === "")){
}
```